# What happens to damane after the Last Battle?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Do we know anything about what happens in the Seanchan Empire regarding damane after the events of the Last Battle? Do they give up collaring them?

Comment: The only future seen past the Last Battle that I'm aware of is Aviendha's vision, which she took action to prevent. They were still grabbing people up to the end though, not likely they'll change that very rapidly

Comment: Aviendha's vision does say that tuon appeared to be leaning towards freeing the demane before her death, so now with the aiel not being at "war" with the seanchan at the end of the novels due to their new roll as "police" Seanchan wont have an active threat that requires channelers to handle, nor combatants to leash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moghedian was collared after the battle itself so I assume they kept at it, in accordance to the Dragon's Peace though. i.e. no more Aes Sedai could be collared, but seems the Sharans were free game so not sure how that applied to the Aiel or windfinders. However a part of the agreement between Tuon and Egwene was any aes sedai who had been collared but wished to be returned would be and any who wished to be collared could be. We never got to see how any of that played out though so I guess it's up to our own interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I recall in one of the earlier books (the Fires of Heaven, "A Short Spear"); Rand & Avi accidentally travel to Seanchan before the return and meet angry military types (including damane) who enigmatically say "There is sedition in this district".  Something tells me that unless Tuon or eventual heirs actively free the damane, there will **always** be enough "sedition" to make damane a valuable military asset.

So ... no.  Per comments, in Avi's vision Tuon is *thinking about* freeing the damane, but unless there's a definitive imperial edict, it'll be a hard sell to the military commanders.

Comment: I absolutely do not agree with you, that from a military perspective, keeping the damane tradition makes sense. Keeping in mind that "there are always more sul'dam than damane", you are wasting the majority of your channelers by not teaching the sul'dam, while also denying yourself linked channelers (the a'dam prevents linking). The only pros damane have, is that essentially the damane itself becomes just a tool, separated from the free will wielding it, thus it is slightly more contained. And now a would be rogue sul'dam can just decide to train herself in secret before going rogue.